# My mex function ignores my if statement

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a mex function that takes in a field of a struct in the third input (i.e. `prhs[2]`), which is a boolean. If true, it will parse information from the fourth input (i.e. `prhs[3]`). In a nutshell, this is the code excerpt:

```
mxValue = mxGetField(prhs[3], 0, "change"); mxLogical *change;
change = mxGetLogicals(mxValue);
mexPrintf("true/false: %i \n", *change); 
mexEvalString("drawnow;");

if ( change ) {
    mexPrintf("...Parsing info... \n");
    mexEvalString("drawnow;");
    mxValue = mxGetField(prhs[3], 0, "info");   
    nRows = mxGetM(mxValue); nCols = mxGetN(mxValue);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> info((double *)mxGetPr(mxValue),nRows);

}
```

As you can see, I do a printout to see whether the input `prhs[2]` is true or false. Even if the function prints out false, the if statement gets executed regardless, because I can see the printout `...Parsing info...`.

Why is my MATLAB mex function ignoring my if statement?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are trying to get a logical from the 4th argument, not the 3rd. I don't see `prhs[2]` anywhere in your code.

Comment: That said, you should also check `nrhs` before indexing into the `prhs` vector.

Comment: Looks like `change` is a pointer so `if(change)` checks if it is not NULL, which is true (albeit can contain a value of 0). Try `if(*change)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is not MATLAB! C is C!

You are checking if pointer `change` has a value. It does indeed have a value, a memory direction e.g. `#72BA21`, to the location where the value of the boolean is stored.

You can either check the contents of whats inside that specific direction `if(*change)` as @buzjwa suggest, or grab the information on the array, instead of a pointer to it, using `mxGetData`.

---

As a side note: learn to debug, or at least, print statements. a simple `mexPrintf()` call would have shown you what `change` contains